# Проблема со статической линковкой программы, в которую нужно слинковать еще и динамическую библиотеку

Tags: c, gcc, linux

У меня есть исполняемый файл (который получаю компилируя MyProg.c). Раньше я к нему статически линковал библиотеку (libMyL.so).

Вот так создаётся библиотека:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c f1.c f2.c f3.c -Ilib
gcc -shared f1.o f2.o f3.o -o libMyL.so -lrt -lpthread
```

Вот так линкуется полученная библиотека к программе:

```
gcc MyProg.c -L. -lMyL -o MyProg
```

Соответственно, чтобы программа запускалась на другом компе libMyL.so должен лежать например в `/lib`.

Всё работает. Но теперь мне нужно слинковать, желательно, абсолютно всё статически. Т.е., чтобы не было зависимости от библиотек и можно было бы перенести на компьютер с такой же архитектурой.

Т.е. например, если я хочу собрать исполняемый файл и запихнуть в него все библиотеки я делаю так:

Содержимое файла Hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    printf( "Hello world!" );
    return 0;
}

gcc -static Hello.c -o Hello
```

Файл Hello получается 500 Кб. Всё ок. Аналогично мне нужно и с MyProg + libMyL.so. Нужно, видимо, чтобы и в MyProg всё было собрано статически, а в libMyL.so запихнуть все зависимости. То, что получится большой объём - ничего страшного. Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Так в чём сложность? Разве нельзя просто залинковать статически? Или собрать либу так, чтобы на выходе были *.a\*.la файлы вместо .so ?

Comment: а как это сделать и как потом статически её прилинковать к приложению? Я пробую у меня постоянно выдаётся ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Ну так... текст ошибки в студию!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делать статические библиотеки очень просто.

1. Компилируем текст в объектный файл (без -fPIC).
2. Создаем библиотеку с помощью утилиты ar примерно так:

   ar crv libmylibrary.a f1.o f2.o

В результате получается статическая библиотека, содержащая нужные модули. Она всегда имеет окончание .a  и префикс lib.
Подключать проще простого:

gcc Hello.c -o myprog -L. -lmylibrary

Если есть на диске и статическая, и динамическая библиотеки с одним именем, то по умолчанию линкуется динамическая. Для линковки статической пользуй ключ -static. И еще совет - в строке сборки пиши статическую библиотеку в конце, после тех модулей, которые имеют на нее ссылку. То же, если 2 библиотеки, одна из которых зависит от другой: от которой зависит - в конец. Избегай взаимной зависимости двух статических библиотек.

А вообще, все это описано почти в любой книге по программированию в Линуксе. Найди и читай.